# Access controller variable within jade loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pug

Sorry if this question has already been asked but I couldn't find the answer...

I have an angularJS app using jade as the render engine.

In my controller I have the following variable defined:

```
var length = 3;
```

In my jade view I would like to access this variable within a loop function:

```
select.form-control
- for (var i = 0; i < #{length}; ++i){
      option i
- }
```

But the #{length} doesn't seem to work...

Thanks

Comment: just to be clear, are you passing in length in render `res.render('your_template', { length: 3 })`

Comment: Actually, I don't pass the variable directly... I use ExpressJS for the routes/rendering and my controller (where length is defined) is linked to my view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following inside your controller:

```
$scope.length = 3;
```

Then it becomes available globally within your Jade template.